# What are the exact sources of CARES Act economic transfers?

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation, soft-question, covid-19-crisis

The bill [Coronavirus Aid, Relief, and Economic Security Act](https://files.taxfoundation.org/20200325223111/FINAL-FINAL-CARES-ACT.pdf) provides "2 trillion".  (There is also [H.R.6201 - Families First Coronavirus Response Act](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/house-bill/6201/text?loclr=bloglaw) providing aid.)

From which sources will the government pay for this?  For instance, how much is in the government ``wallet'' right now?  Is there are form of money printing planned for this?  Any form of loan being made so that the government has a way to pay for the economic aid?

Another question I plan to ask, but that you may ignore it for the moment, is: as this money is consumed by society, can we expect to see a rise in inflation in the years to come?  What does macroeconomic theory say?

Comment: "a rise in inflation in the years to come" compared to what?  If the alternative is a collapse in demand and then in prices (consider what has happened to oil prices recently), a rise in prices due to additional public money distributed to companies and consumers may balance this out, or exceed it, or be insufficient to offset it.

Comment: Compared to today's prices.  You're saying transfers pressure the prices up, right?  But there may be other reasons that could balance the end result out.  So it's not easy to know.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Then nobody knows: it could be too much or too little or Goldilocks (just right)

Comment: What if you assume all variables remain the same but the government spends a large sum of money by distributing it to a lot of people and companies?  (But assume the this is money the government really owns.  So let's say it sold various properties and amassed a couple trillion units of money.)

Comment: The government is going to encourage the financing of the  2 trillion dollar stimulus to the FED and this will take place through the FED purchasing US treasuries.
This is actually taking place now as The Federal Reserve Bank of New York will purchase  37 billion in Treasury bonds to boost liquidity in the crucial government debt market, announced on the 13th. (https://thehill.com/policy/finance/487427-ny-fed-to-accelerate-bond-purchases-to-keep-treasury-market-flowing)

Comment: As of this post the U.S. government's public debt is $23 trillion as tax revenue has fallen and federal spending continues to rise. ( https://www.treasurydirect.gov/NP/debt/current )

Comment: But @MikeJ, from where does the government take the money to buy treasuries?  (How much to spend does have it have right now?)  (Thanks very much for the public debt reference.)

Comment: The government issues bonds that the Federal Reserve buys in open market operations in order to increase the money supply.     The money in turn is used  for governmental initiatives.

Comment: Are you saying the government will sell bonds to raise the 2 trillion mostly?  Is that how it's usually done?  (The government doesn't have a savings account with money ready to be spent?  If they do, I would like to check the balance.)

Comment: I had not found that question.  Understood.  I apologize for any inconvenience.  Thanks!